# HTTP Live Streaming with Android 2.x

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

Since Android (officially) support HLS starting with 3.0 I've looked at different ways to include hls in my app.

1. use a lib like the nexstreaming (pretty expensive)
2. use a HTML 5 player (hls not working on some 2.3 devices)
3. utilize plugin players like vitamio

My Problem is, that possibility number 3 works best, but my client doesn't want the users to see that a plugin is used.

Is there a way to include another apk / install it without prompting the user? 
Or maybe someone has a completly different idea on playing hls on 2.x .

Comment: You have to integrate some library into your app if you don't want to depend on an external one like vitamio since you can't install other apps without prompting the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact vov.io and buy a commercial license for vitamio. Then you could bundle it in your apk. It's still going to be way cheaper than nextreaming.

Comment: actually I'm trying that, but I got no response from them (sent 2 mails about 2-3 weeks ago)

Comment: Nextreaming is well over 30,000$ for a license.

Comment: @qedejavu, do you received a reply jet? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Vitamio is free(means charge) for `personal/commercial` use so far...